# How to chain timers?

Tags: android, timer, handler, delay, chain

Okay so I have a rather weird problem here:
I have one method calling a sequence of delayed methods, for example:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            flash(true, 3000);
            flash(false, 1200);
        }
});
```

And the flash function goes:

```
private void flash(final boolean color, int duration) { 

    // SLEEP duration MILLISECONDS HERE ...

    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            changeColour(color);
        } 
    }, duration);
}
```

What happens is that the 1200 ms timer kicks off before the 3000 ms timer although the 3 second one should go first. I tried adding a trigger for the timers but that only freezes the whole app:

```
...
public void onClick(View view) {
    flash(true, 3000);
    while(wait); //stop here until the timer triggers wait to false
    wait = false;
    flash(false, 1200);
}
...
public void run() {
    changeColour(color);
    wait=false;
} 
...
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens is that the 1200 ms timer kicks off before the 3000 ms
>   timer although the 3 second one should go first.

The first should trigger first only if you set the exact time interval on both of them. However, right now you just trigger two flashes, one to be run after 3 seconds and one after 1,5 seconds(*from the current time*).

In order to do what you want you need to take in consideration the time of the first trigger when posting the second message:

```
flash(true, 3000); // post a message after 3 seconds
flash(false, 4200); // post a message after 4,2 seconds(so at 1,2 seconds after the first flash runs)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the last resort: my concern is that stacking, say, a hundred timers in the queue will not work because the adding to queue itself takes some time - it could additionally delay the timers for low values like 50ms.

Comment: @Sincress Some offsets will happen but calling `flash()` in a loop with different increasing time intervals shouldn't make a visible delay.

Comment: @Sincress If my answer helped you could mark it as correct by clicking the check mark near the answer.